# 14 team schedule play 8 events in 8 rounds

Tags: combinatorics

This seems like a simple problem, but I have spent an embarrassing amount of time attempting to solve it to no avail.  I am trying to put a schedule together that has 14 teams playing through 8 different game types in 8 rounds.  This means that during each round, 1 game will not be played, and by the end each team will play at least (and I am wanting this to be at most) one other team twice.

Every event or tournament scheduler focuses on each team playing the other teams at least 2 times, but none of them can have variable locations/events for inputs.  "Balanced round robin" tournaments make sure that each team plays on each side of every field, but this does not concern me because there will not be side A or side B in these games.  When you try to use these schedules and cut it short, there always seem to be a problem of a team or multiple teams playing a certain game multiple times while missing out on another game.

There was a similar questions asked regarding 8 teams and 6 events, but the answer was very different because there were more teams than events in that scenario, where we have the opposite problem of more events than teams.  The answer in that form was given through an application called MiniZinc, which I looked at but I do not know how to code and was unable to use.

Can someone smarter than me help me think through how to get this schedule made?  Thanks!

Comment: Is it correct to assume that every team plays one game per round? So, there are seven matches with two teams each per round? As there are eight rounds, it is not possible for any team to play against all other 13 teams.

Comment: I ended upo just changing things around and having 14 teams with 7 games instead of 8, so its all good now.

Comment: Whoops, I was wanting to type more on that comment.  I don't care about each team playing every other team, just that tevery team plays every game.  It is for a summer camp game schedule, not a typical sporting event.  The kids care about the games much more than playing every other team.  Thanks though!